# Handle different responses in retrofit2

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

I have an Api which returns two different responses.

On success the response is -

```
{status="", message="", token="", subscription_active=""}
```

On failure the response is -

```
{
    "status": "failed",
    "message": "",
    "errors": []
}
```

Here's the way I am handling the parsing of data -

```
 Call<Object> call = jsonApi.hitOtp(otpPost);

       call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body());

                if(response.body() instanceof OtpSuccessResponse){
                     Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, otpSuccRes.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

I'm getting the success response in log but the if condition is not working. Instead I'm getting -

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException 


com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to 
com.avaskm.yellowalleyproject.Retrofit.Otp.OtpSuccessResponse
```

My OnSuccess pojo class -

```
public class OtpSuccessResponse {


   @SerializedName("status")
   @Expose
   private String status;
   @SerializedName("message")
   @Expose
   private String message;
   @SerializedName("token")
   @Expose
   private String token;

   @SerializedName("subscription_active")
   @Expose
   private String subscriptionActive;

   public OtpSuccessResponse(String status, String message, String token, String subscriptionActive) {

      this.status = status;

      this.message = message;

      this.token = token;

      this.subscriptionActive = subscriptionActive;
   }


}
```

Comment: The `instanceof` in the `if` should not cause a `ClassCastException` so it seems like the issue must be elsewhere.  Where is `otpSuccRes` defined and where is it assigned a value?

Comment: OtpSuccess is the OnSuccess pojo class i hav mentioned

Comment: I am not referring to the class.  I am referring to the variable in this line, `Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, otpSuccRes.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  It is not defined in the code you provided.

Comment: Yes i have defined it forget to provide it here, my bad

Comment: Please post the code that assigns a value to `otpSuccRes`.  It is possibly the issue since `instanceof` should not cause a `ClassCastException`.  Please also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Following these suggestions will help you get an answer sooner.